# Add multiple conditional statement in insert query

Tags: mysql, sql

To ensure some form of referential integrity in Myisam (Mysql) I am trying to do updates and insert using subqueries. For example for updating I use this:

```
update tbl_a
set col_a='test'
where ID=22 and '2' IN (SELECT ID FROM tbl_b) and '33' IN (SELECT ID FROM tbl_c)
```

However the same principle for inserts doesn't work; it tried something like this:

```
insert into tbl_a
(
a,
b,
c
)
values
(
  now(),
  select ID from tbl_b where ID=2,
  select ID from tbl_c where ID=23
)
```

Any idea how to specify (multiple) conditions during insert?

thanks
Patrick

Comment: @Strawberry What's wrong with that syntax? Seems ok to me.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this approach:

```
insert into tbl_a (a, b, c)
select now(), b.id, c.id from tbl_b b, tbl_c c where b.id=2 and c.id=23
```

Comment: INSERT ... SELECT is probably the way to go. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Comment: @user2022678 If it worked, please accept this answer by pressing the "tick" at its left.